# What is **unknown variable superaccoun** message during postgres 15.1 installation?

Tags: postgresql

I am confused at the step where I have to type the password of a super user, it says "**Unknown variable superaccoun**" The doc I read says that I should expect a "postgres" user there. So, what is this message?
Thx

[image]

Comment: Looks like an installer bug to me.

Comment: @mustaccio This is the official postgres installer.  Should I fill a bug?

Comment: Well, if you have nothing better to do... It looks like a [simple template error](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/edb-installers/blob/02bbbe75273f6ddb0c6388b3e919b101170b6a36/server/i18n/fr.lng#L63), so just define _le mot de passe_ as you normally would and move along.

Comment: I think you should file a bug with EDB, who maintain the installer. This is definitely not good, as is the broken accent earlier.